# IBM Worklight 5.0.5.1 - Direct Update fails in Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

In our project containing the iOS and Android environments,
Suddenly out of no where our Android apps fail when a Direct Update occurs. iOS still works fine.

Is there a way to see what address the direct update function is trying to use to update itself?
Right now all we get is:

> E/WLDroidGap(23185): Failed downloading application update file.

UPDATE::
The environment is
https --> firewall --> netscaler --> worklight server

I did have the network people create a http endpoint in the netscaler, and this works.
So something with the https is giving direct update a problem.

We have noticed that the init call comes back with a response.

```
success: /*-secure-
    D/AppName  (  682): {"gadgetProps":{"directUpdate":{"checksum":328818244,"updateSize":1346819,"availableSkins":["default"]},"ENVIRONMENT":"android"},"userPrefs":{},"WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"device","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.impl.MobileClientData@3ff51267"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"device"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"antiXSRF","attributes":{"savedInstanceId":"l057614d2gsf26emf8lr6kndn1"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"antiXSRF"}},"userInfo":{"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"device","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.impl.MobileClientData@3ff51267"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"device"},"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":"0738882f-8b37-4609-acd5-dc2333438692","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"0738882f-8b37-4609-acd5-dc2333438692"},"WorklightConsole":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"wl_authenticityRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"antiXSRF","attributes":{"savedInstanceId":"l057614d2gsf26emf8lr6kndn1"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"antiXSRF"},"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"NullLoginModule","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"NullLoginModule"},"SampleAppRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"myserver":{"userId":"0738882f-8b37-4609-acd5-dc2333438692","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"0738882f-8b37-4609-acd5-dc2333438692"}}}*/
```

But the call for direct update fails::

```
D/        (  682): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a632910, tid 695
D/dalvikvm(  682): GC_CONCURRENT freed 313K, 5% free 8477K/8903K, paused 18ms+35ms, total 133ms
E/WLDroidGap(  682): Failed downloading application update file.
```

Its hard to diagnose since it seems that IBM catches the IOException and gives a canned message

Answer (score 1):

Our problem turned out to be that the certificate on the server changed, and the whole chain was not imported to the server.  Since it was from a certificate authority that was not trusted by android we needed the whole chain(IOS did trust this authority that is why it did not show the problem).

The reason that the init works but the update did not is: init is done by the webview, if android manifest xml has debug on, the web view allows for untrusted certs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in Production or during Development?

- The Direct Update destination is hard-coded; it cannot be changed and it is the server that the app connects to.
- What happens after you clear the app cache?
- Is there still enough storage space in the device?

Comment: This is production and test, the two environments that have a load balancer in front.  the load balancer admins want to know what the path is before they listen to me.  Since both IOS and Android are using the same context root, they belive it has nothing to do with them.  This happens on all android devices.  i have also created new binaries and installed them, still have the problem.

Comment: After the app connects to the Worklight Server, you can see in the response (in LogCat) a checksum value; if this checksum value (stored in the Worklight Server database) is different than the app's web resources checksum (stored in the device), then there will be a Direct Update. The Direct Update URL is static and it is the Worklight Server address.

Comment: In your test server, what happens if you delete the Android environment (via Worklight Console, there is an 'x' next to the environment name) and re-deploy the youApp-android-1.0.wlapp? If possible, add the actual LogCat.

Comment: Also would be useful to know your server topology - how many servers, how many databases. Please edit the question with this information.

Comment: Updated above, we have found that if we use http instead of https direct update works.  Not sure why this would be a problem now, since the env has been running for a while

Comment: Thanks,Will Delete question.  The problem seems to be certificate based, client changed the ssl cert.  What threw us off is the init call went through, although the update did not, that part is a mystery.

Comment: Sure, you can go ahead and delete the question.

Comment: Turns out the reason that the init works but the update did not is: init is done by the webview, if android manifest xml has debug on, the web view allows for untrusted certs.  But the direct update uses the native api, which does not

Comment: @tik27, please provide an answer and mark it as Answered.